# Adding bottom margin to Wordpress GTranslate plugin

Tags: padding, margin, flags

I am using the wordpress gTranslate plugin but on mobile the flags are hovering over the menu button so I want to have a space at the bottom but the flags are called "img" and when I give space to the img element all "img" (images) gets spaces. (In short, how can I change the code (img) of the flags?

I give space at the bottom of the img but all other images on the site get spaces